# Finding the top 3 values and returning the column ID

Tags: google-sheets

Thank you beforehand for your kind response.

Problem: I am trying to do a sheet to sort out the 3 top categories of a given range as shown by the attached screen grab.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KpK0.png)

I only managed to get the results by using the "large" command. "=large(range,n)". Using this I got the value but what I need is the column index/id rather than the numeric values.

Any ideas on how I would go about achieving this?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Try this: `=MATCH(MAX(A2:E2),A2:E2,0)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.

I tried the formula and it returned the row number(?) and not the column id. Like if column D had the largest value, it should return the value "D" so that later I can put in an if statement to find the animal type.

Comment: Look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/316239/how-to-get-the-current-column-name-in-excel) please. This way is not recommended. You can use `=INDEX(MATCTH(...))` instead. Try this: `=INDEX(A1:E5;1; MATCH(MAX(A2:E2);A2:E2;0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible in `arrayformula`.

Using `vlookup`, a sequence of numbers for the search key:

```
=arrayformula(sequence(max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1,columns(A:E)))
```

[image]

...and a range of columns that are sorted by each row of numbers:

```
=arrayformula({
sequence((max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1)*columns(A1:E1)),
sort({
array_constrain(int((row(A2:A)-2)/(columns(A:E)))+1,(max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1)*columns(A1:E1),1),
array_constrain(iferror(split(flatten(if(A2:E<>"",A1:E1&char(9999),)&A2:E),char(9999)),),(max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1)*columns(A1:E1),2)
},1,1,3,0)
})
```

[image]

The final formula for the solution, in cell `G2`:

```
=arrayformula(
array_constrain(
vlookup(
sequence(max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1,columns(A:E)),
{sequence((max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1)*columns(A1:E1)),sort({array_constrain(int((row(A2:A)-2)/(columns(A:E)))+1,(max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1)*columns(A1:E1),1),array_constrain(iferror(split(flatten(if(A2:E<>"",A1:E1&char(9999),)&A2:E),char(9999)),),(max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1)*columns(A1:E1),2)},1,1,3,0)}
,3,0),
max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1,3)
)
```

[image]

It will work with blank cells in some of the rows.

The width of the source data is determined by:

`=columns(A1:E1)`

and the height of the source 'numbers' by:

`=max(if(A:E<>"",row(A:A),))-1` (it needs to sit within an `arrayformula`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, @Aresvik. So detailed and expertly explained. Than kyou so much for the wonderful lesson.

Comment: Updated solution to ignore blank cells.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but after I have more than 20 rows of data, the formula stops working for all the cells with an error #REF! Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size expected 414 actual 1.

Any ideas what went wrong and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Can you share your sheet with the 20 rows of data so I can check it?

Comment: I took a copy of my sheet and had over 30 rows which seemed to work fine. I then flexed it to 1,000 and got the same error you mention. I then deleted all rows but 30 and I still get the error. I think it must be a Google limitation somehow. I've done further tests with a second sheet and it broke after 200 rows. Another test and this sheet works fine with over 500 rows: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vSwXa6h44UiRZ3zi_2IbB8Ap5-oDz-HTIbuVGxmQAZA/copy

Answer (score 3):

Try the following maybe:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({A$1:E$1;A2:E2}),"Select Col1 Order by Col2 desc limit 3"))
```

Comment: Ooopp.... it got it wrong. It keeps giving me an error 

It keeps saying NO_COLUMN: Col2.... any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @O'NeilChung, strange. It works flawlessly on my end. See the edited screenshot with the result when I past the formula in `G2` and drag it down the rows. It would only error out if you somehow changed the formula and the input for the query.

Comment: `=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({A$1:E$1**,**A2:E2}),"Select Col1 Order by Col2 desc limit 3"))` This is not a comma, but a semicolon.

Comment: @BorisBaublys, that's it. When I changed my settings from Dutch to US that's indeed what shows. The answer is ammended.

Comment: YES!!! That was it Boris! Thank you so much to both JvdV and to Boris for the help. You all are amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: An additional question, can I put the formula into an ArrayFormula command?

Comment: While I wrote a solution to get the letter of a column from its index, JvdV made for you Top3.
I'll leave my solution here, maybe it will come in handy for someone: 
`=REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH(MAX(A2:E2,1),A2:E2,0),4),"\D+")`

Comment: I've learnt so much today and it's all thanks to you, Boris and JvdV. Both of you and Muhammet are amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried this: 

=ArrayFormula(IF (ROW(A:A)=1,"",(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({A$1:F$1;(A2:A):(F2:F)}),"Select Col1 Order by Col2 desc limit 3")))))

But ti keeps giving me the same result on every row

Comment: @O'NeilChung. It's probably possible with a long wieldy formula that I don't know about. I'll leave that for someoneelse to figure out =)

Answer (score 1):

you may use this superior formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FILTER(
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A2:E="",,ROW(A2:A)&"×"&A2:E&"×"&A1:E1)), "×"),
 "select Col3 where Col2 is not null order by Col1,Col2 desc"), COUNTIFS(
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A2:E="",,ROW(A2:A)&"×"&A2:E&"×"&A1:E1)), "×"),
 "select Col1 where Col2 is not null order by Col1,Col2 desc"), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A2:E="",,ROW(A2:A)&"×"&A2:E&"×"&A1:E1)), "×"),
 "select Col1 where Col2 is not null order by Col1,Col2 desc"), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:E), 1, ROW(A2)), "<="&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:E), 1, ROW(A2)))<4)&
 FLATTEN(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(MAX((A2:E<>"")*ROW(A2:A)), 3)*
 {"a", "a", 0})),,9^9), 0)), " ")), 9^9, 3))
```

[image]

Comment: I just have to comment again on how amazing this line of code is....... My mind is blown!!!